# Derivative and tall-pipe of truck

Tags: derivatives

Some trucks has vertical tall-pipe with a moving (or fluttering) latch.

Am I right that latch's movement is a derivative of accelerator's movement (or amount of exhaust gas leaving pipe)?

Comment: I doubt there's an exact correspondance between the rate at which your foot moves on the accelerator and the amount the latch on the tailpipe moves.  Consider for example that your motor will have to work harder going uphill than down regardless of what your foot is doing.

Comment: OK, then just correlation between amount of gas and latch's movement - is it derivative?

Comment: It's possibly related.  But even then I doubt it's exactly proportional to the derivative.  If it's a homework problem then that might be what they want you to assume, though.

Comment: The movement of the flap has nothing much to do with the derivative of the accelerator's movement - taking that literally, you can 'move' the accelerator and moments later the engine will rev higher and produce more exhaust, then the flap will move up, but now the accelerator is not moving so has zero derivative.   Alternatively, if you were to slowly push the accelerator with uniform velocity, the flap would gradually rise, but the derivative of the motion is constant, yet the flap still moves up.  I don't want to appear pedantic, but this is a not a well thought out question.